# How can I set data in a Constructor if all parameters are private?

Tags: java, constructor

I have to write a code for example

```
public class Student {
  private int id;
  private String name; 

public Student (int id, String name) {
  this.id=id;
  this.name=name;
 }
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

Now, in MAIN CLASS I have to get all values from user

How am I supposed to set value in constructor??
like this?

```
 String name = input.nextLine(); 
 int id = input.nextInt();

 Student student = new Student (id, name);
```

"THE ISSUE WITH THIS METHOD IS THAT, WE CAN'T KEEP THE ATTRIBUTES PRIVATE THEN, BECAUSE THEY ARE NOW LOCAL VARIABLES"

OR

I create a constructor with no parameters and use that object to get values and set in fully parametrized constructor.

```
 Student st = new Student();
 student.setName(input.nextLine());
 student.setID(input.nextInt());

Student student = new Student (st.getId, st.getName);
```

I don't know if I was able to explain what I want, but if you get that, do let me know

Comment: Your first approach is fine.

Comment: If I use the first method, how can I protect my attributes, as they all become public then.

Comment: there is no problem with what you've done. remember: those local variables aren't alive as long as the object is, nor are they part of your object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use this approach

```
Student st = new Student();
st.setName(input.nextLine());
st.setID(input.nextInt());
```

But both are fine . You don't really need to create the second student object in the second example. Just use the one you created upfront

To access the name and ID later you can do

```
String name = st.getName();
int id = st.getID();
```

(Edit - this assumes you do make a no arg constructor)

Comment: Your approach wouldn't compile, since there is no non-parameter constructor.

Comment: Sure I just assumed he would make the no arg constructor